# CSS: Showing only a relevant subset of a DIV

Tags: css

I need to style some HTML-Markup I have no direct control of and am trying to show just a relevant subset of a div, while hiding everything else.

**The div to style**

```
<div id="spam_and_ham_mix">
    Irrelevant, looooooooong text (--> should be hidden)
    <div id="ham">Important stuff (--> should be visible)</div>
</div>
```

**The desired result**

I want that only the "important stuff" to show up, while hiding everything else.

**1st attempt**

```
#spam_and_ham_mix { display:none; }  /* CSS-Weight 100 */
#spam_and_ham_mix #ham { display:block; }  /* CSS-Weight 200 */
```

Result: the div remains completely hidden, showing nothing at all.

**2nd attempt**

```
#spam_and_ham_mix { visibility:hidden; }  /* CSS-Weight 100 */
#spam_and_ham_mix #ham { visibility:visible; }  /* CSS-Weight 200 */
```

Result: The irrelevant text is invisible, but it still takes the same space as if it were visible (which is in line with the CSS-specification but not the desired result):

**Question**

What can I do about it?

I am looking for a CSS-only solution (if possible).

Comment: I don't know you can do anything without wrapping that other (non-printable) text in markup that can be specifically hidden, or move the other out.

Comment: @Jared: That was not what I am hoping for (but what I was starting to suspect) -- if that's the answer I'll accept it. But I'm still hoping for a solution...

Comment: Well, maybe I spoke too soon: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/kqUUN/ Have not checked all browsers, but in FF13 that works. Also, there's usually few reasons to chain `#id #id` selectors like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NOTE** - This answer is intended for situations that exist that are not expected to impact search engine optimization (SEO). In other words, print stylesheets and sites/pages where the content is not meant to be crawled by search engines. Doing what's below in those situations may cause a search engine to determine the site is manipulating content, thus possibly negatively affecting search placement or resulting in a ban of some sort. I do not have any evidence this is the case, but be careful if this is your situation.

This seems to work in all the browsers I tested (FF13, Chrome, Opera 12, IE7-9):

```
#spam_and_ham_mix {
    font-size: 0; 
}
#ham {
    font-size: 15px; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/kqUUN/

Feels "hacky" (and not as in "-sacky"), but so do negative margins.

Note as well, you have to be [careful with specificity](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/):

```
#spam_and_ham_mix,
#spam_and_ham_mix .ham {
    font-size: 0;
}
.ham {
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/kqUUN/1/

`.ham` as the lone selector will be overridden by the more "specific" selector, ie, other one.

Comment: It feels hacky to me too, but it works in IE9, Chrome20 on OSX and Win64, and FF. Any ideas what to do, when the irrelevant part is not only text, but also an img, or a submit button etc?

Comment: Set elements to `display: none`. Others if that doesn't work, you may set their `height`/`width` to `0`? What you're trying to accomplish is inherently broken by the way the markup is structured, and what you demonstrated is text. Whatever you apply in the parent must be reversed in the child if you want that to print, which can be problematic. If you can, include a `noprint` class to elements in the parent you want to hide and set it to `display: none`.

Comment: @FelixAlcala - Not "great", but you could do something along these lines for children elements, you would just need to make it complete (consult a reset script for a list of elements): http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/kqUUN/17/ I think a `noprint` class would work better.

Comment: @Jared - I cannot control the html (it comes from a third party) -- I'll have to work around. I like your updated script and will give it a try.

Comment: @FelixAlcala - You could class that listing, so it wasn't tied to a specific `id`'d element, you would really just need to be careful with specificity in that case, since it could be easily overridden.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - By "class that listing" you mean wrap a div with a css-class around the markup shown above? I could do that -- but I'm not sure how that could help. What am I missing?

Comment: No, and when I tried to explain it I realized in your situation it probably won't help a lot. What I meant was: `.i-do-not-want-to-print p, .i-do-not-want-to-print form... {`, but in reality that would need to be `.i-do-not-want-to-print #spam_and_ham p`. There's no benefit for the most part.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Thanks -- this works. Yes, it's hackish, it's by no means "great", but given the markup I have here it does all I need it to do. Thank you!

Comment: @FelixAlcala - I'm glad I could help (I know these types of things can be grippy and annoying to deal with). That zero-font-size trick I figured out recently on another issue, so it was perhaps serendipitous I noticed that earlier and then was able to recall it here.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned images and such, perhaps approach like this could work for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/nYFWw/

CSS:

```
#spam_and_ham_mix { 
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
}
#spam_and_ham_mix #ham { 
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}​
```

HTML ( same as yours ):

```
<div id="spam_and_ham_mix">
    Irrelevant, looooooooong text (--> should be hidden)
    <div id="ham">Important stuff (--> should be visible)</div>
</div>
```

---

You could set `#spam_and_ham_mix { width: 0px; }` but then you'd most likely want to give `#spam_and_ham_mix #ham` a width.

Comment: Well, that is hack, but more or less works. Interesting that overflowed content will still be visible if the parent isn't.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yea, doesn't really work so well if there is other content under the visible content shown in the OP's example.. Unless you'd give `#spam_and_ham_mix` a static height.. :/

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:
http://jsfiddle.net/kqUUN/12/

The only problem there is, you'll have to set the height of the #spam_and_ham_mix manually to whatever you want. Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, you could do that, but it'll only work if the parent is already the same height; if not, you kinda run into problems. The OP mentioned long text, so: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/kqUUN/13/

Comment: Yes, but that's exactly why I said that he would have to set the height manually. See: http://jsfiddle.net/kqUUN/15/

Comment: I think that's less than optimal.

Comment: Well, having this html structure in the the first place is less than optimal, so the solution can only be a dirty fix like this one, which is supported in all browsers.