# How to hide only a part of the content of a li with CSS?

Tags: html, css

In the following code I would like to hide "Hello world" but keep visible my ul.myphotos with CSS.

Here is a sample of what I have:

```
<ul class="content">
    <li>
        Hello world
        <ul class="myphotos">
            <li>Photo1</li>
            <li>Photo2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS: Showing only a relevant subset of a DIV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291231/css-showing-only-a-relevant-subset-of-a-div)

Comment: The answer: Manipulate the `font-size` on the `li` to be `0` and the `font-size` of it's children to be normal. (Or, preferably, put markup around it and select and hide that. Of course, that's not hard at all.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant do that with the code you have atm (well, yes you can with some rather "hacky" tricks...).

I'd propose a clean solution: Wrap that text in a separate tag, e.g.:

```
<ul class="content">
    <li>
        <span>Hello world</span>
        <ul class="myphotos">
            <li>Photo1</li>
            <li>Photo2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And now you can easily say:

```
li > span{
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: Sure you can. See my possible duplicate.

Comment: @JaredFarrish sure you can do this, if you wan't to risk getting listed for blackhat SEO. Also it's a bad habit to work with fixed font-size.

Comment: If it's in a print stylesheet, I doubt that's going to be an issue; if you have other information to disprove that theory, feel free to point it out. Additionally, not every situation requires SEO considerations; if you can't manipulate the markup, there's few choices you have beyond that.

Comment: @Jared true, but you are making assumptions that the OP never stated. But I revised my absolute statement to take these options like font-size and negative margins into account (which I would consider dirty and thus never propose to others).

Comment: Both of what you mention are a fact of how stylesheets work, not a hack (although I felt the same way when I first across them). They're a tool, one that has (as you point) certain considerations to be weighed. It is not inherently wrong to consider their use. And if we're talking about assumptions made, I went off what was literally depicted, so my comments were geared as a response, not a proposal of intent. `:)` It was a valid a point on the SEO angle, though. I'll add that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Put Hello World in `<span>` tags with an id and then hide that.